# convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ if $a_n\geq 0$

My solution is a little bit messy. I found easy solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048143/suppose-suma-n-converges-how-do-i-prove-that-sum-frac-sqrta-nn), but can anyone please tell if my argument is right or not?

Three type of cases can happen:

case 1: $\exists N: \forall n\geq N$ such that, $a_n\geq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$. I this case the solution is immediate.

case 2: $\exists N: \forall n\geq N$ such that, $a_n\leq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$. In this case note that, $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Again converges.

case 3: $\nexists N: \forall n\geq N$ such that, neither $a_n\geq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ nor $a_n\leq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ happens. In that case, we divide the sequence such that for some $n$, $a_n\geq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ and for some $n$, $a_n\leq \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$. Then, case 3 is actually a combination of case 1 and case 2. Hence the series converges in this case too.

Hence, $\sum \dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converges if $a_n\geq 0$

Comment: Your logic in case 2 implies $a_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ but I don't see why that must be true.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048143/suppose-suma-n-converges-how-do-i-prove-that-sum-frac-sqrta-nn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: umm, I did not write case 2 must be true, I said, this is a case, so it is one of a possibility @Trurl